# The prefix word and dot in urls

Tags: django, url

Is there a name for website URLs that look like **noun.mysite.com?** I know it's possible for big players such as, **docs.google.com**.

Is there a particular way to setup URLs like that? Could a small Django powered site do it?

Comment: It's called a subdomain

Answer (score 0):

Any site could do that.  Configure desired domain name in the control panel of your hosting service.